# Setting up Android development on Linux

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

My Operating System is `Ubuntu 64-bit`. Following is the error dialog that prompts when `ADT plugin` installment is finished. I reinstalled everything from the start. But still the same thing happens. Can someone please help rectifying the error? The entire day has gone in vain.

[image]

**P.S:** Have seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972641/ubuntu-64-with-android-64-bundle-cannot-find-adb-executable), but no use. It just says it isn't possible as far as I understand.

Comment: DO you have permission to access that folder??

You have to placed your ADT and SDK (EClipse) in home directory of ubuntu... Try this might help you...

Comment: @Gru Thanks, I have placed SDK in home directory. I am installing ADT in Eclipse(help-> Install new software). So how can I find whether it gets placed in the home directory?

Comment: I think you have added ADT in your eclipse then what is the problem then?? ADT in is embedded eclipse. Try to restart your eclipse and check your problem got solved or not ??