# 64-bit version of adb and fastboot?

Tags: android, linux, adb, fastboot

I'm catching the error below on Debian 7.3, x64 (fully patched).

[image]

I'm pretty certain its because `adb` is 32-bit even in the 64-bit distro of its SDK tools

```
$ which adb 
/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
$ /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
bash: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory
$ file /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, 
version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8,
not stripped
```

I don't want to install hundreds of megabytes of 32-bit binaries just to support `adb` and `fastboot`. (See, for example, [Ubuntu 64 with Android 64 Bundle cannot find adb executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972641/ubuntu-64-with-android-64-bundle-cannot-find-adb-executable)).

I know there's an outstanding feature request from 2012 at [Please port SDK tools to 64-bit on Linux (adb, aapt, etc)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36957), but no action has been taken (even no acknowledgement).

Does anyone know if Google makes a 64-bit version of `adb`? If not, does Google have any plans on providing them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good news. it is now officialy maintained by the fine folks at Debian.

just install `android-tools-adb` (you also have fastboot and a few others) from the main debian repo (no need to add repo as this is there by default)

it is native `amd64` architecture!

```
$ sudo aptitude install android-tools-adb
...
$ file /usr/bin/adb
/usr/bin/adb: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b36a05975f3d903a4f0ee3e02b581cc71ddedf26, stripped
```

Comment: I forgot about this post... Now that I've revisited it, I'm wondering if its on-topic :(

Comment: nah. that is development for android. if you posted it on android, you would be off topic because for some reason they close all development questions there (go figure)

Comment: I use debian myself but I would never use their repository for development tools - their updates take just too long. Anyway Android SDK uses 64-bit tools for some time now. see my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/39541980/1778421

Comment: i still rather be a few months behind but have their scrutiny and reliable distribution channel. but yeah, sometimes i also think it is too much

Answer (score 2):

Nobody comes here looking for answers to this question anymore since the packages distributed with Android SDK come in 64-bit flavor by default now.

So I am just writing down version numbers for the last 32-bit packages for future reference:

- [build-tools_r23.0.3](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r23.0.3-linux.zip)
- [platform-tools_r23.0.1](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running debian/ubuntu 12.04 follow this guide to add the ppa for the  64bit fastboot and adb

http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/245-ubuntu-precise-install-android-sdk

If you do not need the SDK and just need the android-tools, do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

If you want the SDK API on your precise 64 bit, then sorry, you have to install ia32-libs.

Newer than 12.04 (12.10 and above) I think android-tools-adb and android-tools-fastboot 64bit are in the universe respository. No additional PPA necessary.

David

Answer (score -1):

Instead of use a repository, and if you prefer to work with your downloaded Android SDK, you should use this procedure that is decribed [here](http://astroelec.blogspot.fr/2013/05/installing-android-sdk-tools-on-debian.html).

To resume:

Install the Android SDK

Add the i386 MultiArch support to your Debian:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Update your package list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install the following i386 packages

```
sudo aptitude install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386
```

Now, all the Android SDK platform tools should work.

---

Edit (2014/06/06): The solution has been already answered on this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18674848/712182).

---

Comment: question is NOT how to run 32 bit binaries on 64bit linux. Question is: compiling adb in 64 bit is trivial, so where can we find the official version?